# Add content in sales order?

Tags: magento2.2, php-7

How to insert additional block in **create** order page (magento2 admin side order) after billing/ shipping address**

Answer (score 0):

**Create app/code/Rbj/OrderComments/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="order_tab_info" template="Rbj_OrderComments::order/view/tab/info.phtml" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Create phtml file inside

```
app/code/Rbj/OrderComments/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/tab/info.phtml
```